Can Hibernate use a large bridge table to map entities in a tree?
I am trying to use a large bridge table to map my entities that are organized in a tree. We want to use a single bridge table in postgres to maintain all associations instead of having a bridge table for every mapping.
@Table
class TopLevel {
   @Id
   String pk;
   String id;
   List<B> bList;
}

@Table
class B {
   @Id
   String pk;
   List<C> cList;
}

@Table
class C {
   @Id
   String pk;
   List<D> dList;
}


@Table
class D {
   @Id
   String pk;
}

@Table
class EntityData {
   String pk;
   String topLevelId; 
   String bPk;
   String cPk;
   String dPk;
}

And how we want the bridge table to look

entity_data
| pk | top_level_id | b_pk | c_pk | d_pk |
| -- | ------------ | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1  |      1       |   1  |   2  |   1  |
| 2  |      1       |   2  |      |      |

This bridge table should produce a tree where top_level has B1 as a child. B1 has C2 as a child. C2 has D1 as a child. And top_level also has B2 as a child, but its children are null.
Is there a way for me to use hibernate so that when I want to retrieve top_level where the ID is equal to 1, I get the complete tree?
I am thinking A:
use multiple entities that point to this single table as such: entity_data_top_level, entity_data_A, etc. So we can do traditional mappings OneToMany/ManyToOne. But haven't gotten anything working yet. My annotations might be off, but unsure if it's even possible.
Or B:
Don't use Hibernate
I am currently trying to explore option A, but it seems to be getting really complex. Wanted to see if this approach was even supported by Hibernate before I go any further.
Edit
I changed the table to properly reflect how we have it set up in our db
